# Use TEXT function on variable c++

Tags: c++

I wanna use TEXT() on variable full code:

```
LPCTSTR data = TEXT(argv[0]);
```

Or if someone now how to write char variable to LPCTSTR.

Comment: `TEXT()` is a macro, not a function. That's basically the problem why that can't work.

Comment: `TEXT` will only transform a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). Typically what `TEXT` does is stick an `L` on the front of the literal if conversion to wide characters is required. `TEXT("Hello World!")` is the same as `L"Hello World!"` or `"Hello World!"`

Comment: So how to use it ?

Comment: Would using `int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[]);` be an option? Since you try to convert `char*` to `LPCTSTR`, I'm guessing you use Unicode anyway. `LPCTSTR` could be `const char*` or `const wchar_t*`

Comment: Same error nothing changed.

Comment: What error? You never mentioned an error. Put the error message in the question. Note: If you use `wmain` you get `LPCWSTR`'s automatically, no need for `TEXT`. Do you compile this in Unicode mode?

Comment: Side note: `TEXT` was part of a solution for the thorny problem of making the same code compile for the old 8-bit character using, DOS-based Windows versions of the 1990s and for the Unicode using Windows NT-based Windows versions of the mid 1990s to today. Unless you have to support the likes of Windows 95, it's best if you do the program in wide characters end-to-end.

Comment: If you need wide characters because you are calling a Windows API function, you can take the easy way out and turn off Unicode support. To tell you how to do this, we need to know what compiler (and possibly what IDE) you are using. To tell you whether this is a good idea or not, we need more context.

Comment: [Documentation on `wmain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/using-wmain?view=msvc-160) might be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ATL::CA2W:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlconv.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    LPCSTR lpcstr = argv[0];
    ATL::CA2W wtext(lpcstr);
    LPCTSTR lpctstr = wtext.m_psz;

    std::wcout << lpctstr << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: But its not everything what i want.
Let me show more code `LONG setRes = RegSetValueEx(hKey, value, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)data, strlen(data) + 1);
`

Comment: @Natan I recommend expanding on the question to include a broader example with more context. This will allow potential answerers to better target solutions to your problem. All of my comments under the question have been generalities because I don't have enough information to write a good answer.